# Visual Studio install issue

Tags: visual-studio, rpm, yum, rhel7

Trying to install the RHEL version of Visual Studio on one of my RHEL 7 Linux boxes.

Installation instructions state:

```
sudo rpm --import https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc
```

I receive the following when doing so:

```
[root@desectlas014 ~]# rpm --import https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc                     
curl: (7) Failed connect to packages.microsoft.com:443; Connection timed out                                     error: https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc: import read
failed(2).
```

Can you describe what the issue is?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason of this message is your computer can't reach the host `packages.microsoft.com` on port `443`

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem, and didn't find out the reason. However, you can do a workaroud.

```sh
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc
rpm --import microsoft.asc
```